# Print list in desired pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

```
fruits = ["mango", "apple", "grapes", "kiwi", "peaches"]
color = ["yellow", "no color", "green", "no color", "orange"]
taste = ["sweet", "sweet1", "sweet2", "sweet3", "sweet4"]
```

These are the lists and I want the output to be- for every element in fruits if it's color is not `no color` then print it's color else print it's respective taste.
output-

```
[mango, yellow]
[apple, sweet1]
[grapes, green]
[kiwi, sweet3]
[orange, sweet4]
```

I tried with this code but I wasn't able to get the desired output

```
a = []
for i in fruits:
    a.append(i)
    for j in color:
        for k in taste:
            if j != "no color":
                a.append(j)
            else:
                a.append(k)
    print(a)
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Hint: walk me through the logic of your code, explaining it step by step as if I'm completely dumb. By doing so you'll find the (many) mistakes by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something using `zip` and list comprehension.
Basically, the code simplified/broken down, iterates through `fruits, colors & tastes` at the same time using `zip`. We check if the current color we are on is equal to `no color` if so we add only the fruit and taste to `new`. But if we can find a color, we will directly add fruit and color.

```
new = [[fruit,taste] if color == 'no color' else [fruit,color] for fruit,color,taste in zip(fruits,colors,tastes)]
```

**output**

```
[['mango', 'yellow'], ['apple', 'sweet1'], ['grapes', 'green'], ['kiwi', 'sweet3'], ['peaches', 'orange']]
```

Comment: This works and perfect, thanks for your answer. @BuddyBob

Answer (score 2):

You should use plain indexes instead of looping with for loop.

you can just try:

```
output = []
for i in range(len(fruits)):
    fruit = fruits[i]
    if color[i] == 'no color':
        output.append((furit,taste[i]))
    else:
        output.append((fruit,color[i]))
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got my mistakes also @Maged

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate through the index since you have equal length lists

```py
for i in range(len(fruits)):
    if color[i]=="no color":
        print([fruits[i], taste[i]])
    else:
        print([fruits[i], color[i]])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
['mango', 'yellow']
['apple', 'sweet1']
['grapes', 'green']
['kiwi', 'sweet3']
['peaches', 'orange']
```

You can do with list comprehension as well:

```py
[[fruits[i], taste[i]] if color[i]=='no color' 
                        else [fruits[i], color[i]] 
                        for i in range(len(fruits))]
```